# couchbase not returning some documents when using specific index

Tags: couchbase, sql++

By the tests I made, it seems that these are specifically large documents (~2mb) and when the query uses specific indexes (in my case an array index).
It seems to be working ok when the document is smaller.
This happens either in Couchbase dashboard, cbq or the scala SDK i'm using.
I'm using **Couchbase 4.6.0** with **Memory optimized indexes**.

---

I have these indexes relevant to this query:

```
CREATE INDEX `cache_partial_specific`
ON `content`(`docType`,`entityType`,`entityId`) 
WHERE (`docType` = "feedCachePartial") WITH { "defer_build"=true }  

CREATE INDEX `feed_cache_partial_meta`
ON `content`(`meta().id`)
WHERE (`docType` = `feedCachePartial`)  

CREATE INDEX `cache_partial_index`
ON `content`((distinct (array (`url`.`id`) for `url` in `urls` end)))
WHERE (`docType` = "feedCachePartial") WITH { "defer_build"=true }
```

The last is the one causing troubles

---

The problem:

For example When running
`SELECT * FROM content  WHERE meta().id = 'cached:topic:297:grp:all'`

or

`SELECT * FROM content  WHERE docType='feedCachePartial' AND entityId=297 and entityType='topic'`

it returns the documents and I see the url 13319 in the list or urls.

But when running

```
SELECT * FROM content
WHERE docType='feedCachePartial'
AND ANY url IN urls SATISFIES url.id = 13119 END
```

or any variation with the condition `ANY url IN urls SATISFIES url.id = 13119`

the document `cached:topic:297:grp:all` is not returned.

---

The `max_indexer_doc_size` is set to 20 MB so I believe this is not the issue (and either way it is being returned when using the other indexes).

When viewing the query log I see that this specific index i'm using has 1 replica (I have total of 3 index nodes on this cluster).

---

I would have investigate this index and see which documents resize on the index but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but I'm a little confused why your last query would be checking anything other than the document key. Since you know the key, why add the other conditions?

Comment: Have you checked that the problem is the index and not the query? If you just have the primary index, does the query return the correct answer slowly?

Comment: Also, you only need the back-ticks when you are using names with weird characters, like -+%$. I think you could remove the back-ticks in all the statements above.

Comment: @MatthewGroves that was a misprint, I edited it. Thanks

Comment: @JohanLarson What do you refer to by "primary index"? I have 3 GSI indexes related to this query (urls.id, meta().id, docType), on all of it's different variations. Only when i'm using the index on urls.id I don't get the expected result.
And I'm not using back-ticks as far as I am aware, i'm using single quotes.

Comment: @JohanLarson (urls.id, meta().id, docType) -> meaning (urls.id, meta().id, docType/entityType/entityId), e.g  cache_partial_index, feed_cache_partial_meta, cache_partial_specific, (can't edit after 5 minutes)

Comment: What I am calling back-ticks are the symbols around docType, entityType, 
 and entityId in your first index definition. These are unnecessary.

Comment: You can create a primary index like this: `CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON content`. A primary index will let you run most queries on the bucket, though usually somewhat slowly. Secondary GSI indexes are optimizations for speed, not functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your indexer.log and see if the specific index is skipped your document key due to index key size limitations.If the index is not indexed query will not find that document. If you already know the document key and query is not covered best option will be specifying USE KEYS and removing META().id predicate this saves time.

As your documents are large and trying to do ARRAY indexing it might have skipped. If you know document key no need to Array Index directly fetch the document with USE KEYS and apply predicates. If document is skipped due to size limitation check this post https://forums.couchbase.com/t/how-to-read-max-array-seckey-size-setting-version-4-5-1-2844-community-edition-build-2844/16374

```
SELECT * FROM content USE KEYS "cached:topic:297:grp:all" WHERE ....
```

Unless you are doing Search on META().id (example: META().id LIKE "xyz%") feed_cache_partial_meta index may not be useful. You can use USE KEYS.

If documents are small, you can combine the other indexes like this and see if it works and avoid Intersectscans.

```
CREATE INDEX `cache_partial_index`
ON `content`(`docType`,`entityType`,`entityId`, DISTINCT ARRAY url.id FOR url IN urls END)
WHERE (`docType` = "feedCachePartial") WITH { "defer_build"=true };
```

The following blogs has useful info

https://blog.couchbase.com/create-right-index-get-right-performance/
https://blog.couchbase.com/n1ql-practical-guide-second-edition/

Comment: Thanks. That was indeed the problem.
Do you know the reason for this max_array_seckey_size limit? Why does it have a limit specifically for arrays? Is it because arrays are more likely to  consume high RAM?
Should I hesitate to change it to a bigger number (e.g 1GB)?

Comment: If the keysize is bigger size of index record is bigger which impacts performance. You should try with latest version of CB which has been relaxed this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll just take my simplest guess here, but in this query

```
SELECT * FROM content
where docType='feedCachePartial'
and meta().id = 'cached:topic:297:grp:all'
AND entityId=297
and entityType='topic'
AND ANY url IN c.urls SATISFIES url.id = 13119 END
```

is the "c" in the "c.urls" correct? Or should the first line say `SELECT * FROM content c`?

Comment: That was a misprint, I edited it now with the fixed query